# git merge two repositories into a new one, one should be a branch

Tags: git, merge, repository, branch, visual-sourcesafe

I want to bring to repositories together, but the second repository should go into a branch

```
A - B - C - D -  E -  F - G - H Repo1

           A1 - B1 - C1 Repo2
```

Crete new repo reponew

```
git init reponew
```

Add a remote for and fetch the old repo Repo1

```
git remote add -f Repo1 ..\..\output\Repo1
```

Merge the files from Repo1/master into new/master

```
git merge Repo1/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

The new repository reponew looks like:

```
A - B - C - D -  E -  F - G - H master
```

Now I've created a new branch on specific commit and checkout

```
git branch branchX 200303b0b215cc0fb2d92f50ffc9d7df8bbaab74
git checkout branchX
```

Add a remote for and fetch the old repo Repo1

```
git remote add -f Repo2 ..\..\output\Repo2
```

Merge the files from Repo1/master into new/master

```
git merge -Xtheirs Repo2/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

And now the new repository repnew looks like this:

```
                 A1 - B1 - C1 branchX
                                     \
A - B - C  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
          \
           D - E - - - - - F - G - H master
```

It looks like that this is caused by the merge request which has a merge date of now

But I owuld like that it look like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - - - - - F - G - H master
          \
            - - - A1 - B1 - C1 branchX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main way to "move" commits **AFTER** an existing history is to use [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). Merge can only add a new commit with both histories as parents.
But `rebase` will not really move the commist but replay them after the specified `onto`. So, if there is still a reference (branch or tag) on the old commits, they will stay available in the whole commit history.

In your case you want to rebase the history of `Repo2/master` onto the commit `C`.

So the solution is:

```
git branch branchX --no-track Repo2/master
git rebase -Xtheirs 200303b0b215cc0fb2d92f50ffc9d7df8bbaab74 branchX
```

You should get the result you want.

---

Suggested by @torek, there is also [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). 
`filter-branch` allows you to rewrite a commit history by applying a filter on each rewritten commit. It's mainly used to remove wrongly committed sensitive data (such as password), to remove large files from history, or to change the root folder of a repository.
The advantage of `filter-branch` is that it will also move the tags.
It will also filter commits with empty message.

With `filter-branch`, there is a `--parent-filter` that allow you to change the parent(s) of a commit while filtering.
It will filter all the references listed, so to move tags, we have to list all tags in current `branchX`: `git tag --merged branchX`, then filter them as-is with `--tag-name-filter cat`.

So the command will be:

```
git branch branchX --no-track Repo2/master
git filter-branch \
    --parent-filter 'test $GIT_COMMIT = <FULL-commit-id-of-A1> && echo "-p 200303b0b215cc0fb2d92f50ffc9d7df8bbaab74" || cat' \
    --tag-name-filter cat \
    -- branchX $(git tag --merged branchX)
```

Then you will have the rewritten history, but still the old one available with references prefixed by `refs/original/`.

If it's OK, you can remove the original references (`rm -rf .git/refs/original/`), otherwise you can restore them (`cp -r .git/refs/original/refs .git && rm -rf .git/refs/original/`).

Comment: Thanks zigarn, is it possible that the git rebase command will also allow empty commit messages, because the most of the commits (vss2git used) has none ?

Comment: No idea, I guess not. In this case, I think git will prompt you a commit message or stop the rebase: in first case simply validate an empty message and you should be able to go back to second case in which you can explicitly commit with `--allow-empty-message` then continue rebase with `git rebase --continue`

Comment: It's not quite the *only* way; or, from a different point of view, there is *no* way. In all cases, you must *copy* the original commits to new, slightly different commits: the difference being that the new `A1'` copy of `A1` has a parent, and the new `B1'` copy of `B1` has `A1'` as its parent, and so on. The user commands that can do this directly are rebase and filter-branch. You can also use `git replace` in a rather complicated manner (that, despite being complicated, is simpler than doing it all at once with `git filter-branch`!).

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, a non-interactive `git rebase` *does* allow you to keep "empty" (no-changes-to-files) commits: add `-k` to the flags. If you mix this with interactive rebase there are some annoying failure modes, so it's best to just do it non-interactively.

Comment: please could you tell us how to use it git filter-branch in detail

Comment: Updated my answer to add the `filter-branch` option. Thanks @torek, it was a good point and a better solution.

Comment: Many thanks thats it what i was looking for, changed the command a little bit and add after the --parent-filter line the following line: --tag-name-filter cat \ now it is good and solved. thanks again

Comment: During my tests, I found that the `--tag-name-filter` wasn't necessary but may have mixed with previous tests. Add it to the answer.